# what does > this icon means in package explorer in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I find there is ">" before my .java file in package explorer.
Anyone know what that means? [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a source control system such as SVN this normally means you have 'outgoing' modifications pending on the file. In other words you have changed the file and not yet checked it in.

Answer (score 2):

The ">" symbol before files in your Project Explorer view will flag the file as having differences from the source control host you are connected to. You can drill down through a package until you find the file that differs from the current source control version. Each container that nests an uncommitted item will have the ">".

In Eclipse, you are able to see what changes differ between the local version and the VCS host by right clicking the file > Compare With > Latest From HEAD.